# opengl es 2.0 - optimizing fragment shader

Tags: opengl-es-2.0, glsl

I am developing a game for Android/iOS and need to optimize the rendering. 
The game enables the user to deform terrain so i am using a gray scale image for the terrain (value of 1 in the terrain means solid ground, and 0 means no ground) and applying a fragment shader on it (there is also a background image). This works very well with 60 fps constant, but the problem is that i also need to render a border on the terrains edge. So to do so i blur the edges when deforming and in the fragment shader i draw the border based on the terrains density/transparency (the border is a 1x64 texture).

The problem is that when rendering the border i need to do a dynamic texture read which drops the frame rate to 20. Is there any way i could optimize this? If i would replace the border texture with a uniform float array would it help or would it be the same as reading from a 2d texture?

The shader code:

```
 varying mediump vec2 frag_background_texcoord;
 varying mediump vec2 frag_density_texcoord;
 varying mediump vec2 frag_terrain_texcoord;

 uniform sampler2D density_texture;
 uniform sampler2D terrain_texture;
 uniform sampler2D mix_texture;
 uniform sampler2D background_texture;

 void main()
 {
    lowp vec4 background_color = texture2D(background_texture, frag_background_texcoord);
    lowp vec4 terrain_color = texture2D(terrain_texture, frag_terrain_texcoord);

    highp float density = texture2D(density_texture, frag_density_texcoord).a;

    if(density > 0.5)
    {
         lowp vec4 mix_color = texture2D(mix_texture, vec2(density, 1.0)); <- dynamic texture read (FPS drops to 20), would replacing this with a uniform float array help (would also need to calculate the index in the array)?
         gl_FragColor = mix(terrain_color, mix_color, mix_color.a);
    } else
    {
         gl_FragColor =  background_color;
    }
 }
```

Comment: did you tried to move texture reads from this if? that way it could be optimized by gpu probably.

Comment: yes, it was even slower :/

Comment: I am not sure what you are trying to accomplish by setting density to `highp`. `sampler2D` defaults to `lowp`, so you are not gaining any precision by storing the result of the lookup in a `highp` variable; you are just wasting GPU cycles converting it to `highp` and then creating a high precision `vec2` for the texture coordinate.

Comment: In fact, `highp` is not even required to work in fragment shaders unless the pre-processor macro: `GL_FRAGMENT_PRECISION_HIGH` is set to `1` by the implementation. You should be checking this value before attempting to use `highp` in a fragment shader.

Comment: thanks for the tips but the biggest performance increase was to remove branching, see my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out. The way i fixed it was to remove all branching. Runs of ~60fps now. 
The optimized code:

```
varying mediump vec2 frag_background_texcoord;
varying mediump vec2 frag_density_texcoord;
varying mediump vec2 frag_terrain_texcoord;

uniform sampler2D density_texture;   
uniform sampler2D terrain_texture;
uniform sampler2D mix_texture;
uniform sampler2D background_texture;

void main()
{
   lowp vec4 background_color = texture2D(background_texture, frag_background_texcoord);
   lowp vec4 terrain_color = texture2D(terrain_texture, frag_terrain_texcoord);

   lowp vec4 mix_color = texture2D(mix_texture, vec2(density, 0.0));
   lowp float density = texture2D(density_texture, frag_density_texcoord).a;

   gl_FragColor = mix(mix(bg_color, terrain_color, mix_color.r), mix_color, mix_color.a);       
}
```